# Cannot boot anymore. Disk suddenly empty?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

So, a friend of mine worked on his laptop, walked to the kitchen, came back 5 minutes later and saw this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

So apparently, for some reason the laptop rebooted and couldn't boot anymore from the hard drive. We tried to remove the hard drive and connect it via USB, to exclude any errors from internal cables or connections. But it still did not work.

As a next step, I attached the hard drive to my laptop via USB to see if Windows recognize it. When I open the windows disc manager, the hard drive looks like this:

[image]

So it looks as if the disk were empty and unpartitioned. I also did a quick check on bad sectors, and it seems the drive is fine.

There definitely should be data on the hard drive. Windows is installed and he had a lot of documents and whatnot on the drive. How can it be, that it suddenly shows as completely empty and not bootable anymore? Any hints on how I can repair the disk to a) keep the files and b) make it bootable again would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:** Tried to scan the drive with EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard. The drive is shown as having a "Lost partition" and after a few minutes, it seems the drive disconnects itself and I need to retry. Very odd.

**Update 2:** ddrescue yields this. any opinions?

[image]

**Update 3:** CrystalDiskInfo yields the following. Why does this make it seem that everything is good?

[image]

Comment: Drives do "just die" which is why backups are vital. How old is it? That first screen's copyright is 2013. I'd recommend a data recovery company rather than user DIY if it really is that old.

Comment: The first screen is the PXE (network) boot ROM, probably started when no other boot device could be found. Might be completely separate from the system BIOS so i.m.o. does not really indicate this system is from 2013.

Comment: Laptop was bought September 2016.

Comment: @StarCat - sorry, wasn't aware of that. I think the rest of my comment still hold good, though. After the OP's edit, I'd be very wary of DIY recovery.

Comment: Currently scanning with TestDrive and there seem to be a lot of errors... How can this happen that a disk fails from one minute to another.

Comment: Was there something omitted, such as the machine being dropped while running?

Comment: Stop attempts of home recovery! You can now easily stress a disk up to the point when it die completely and nobody would be able to rescue anything. If data has any value, really better to find a recovery professional and give it to them.

Comment: @beta "How can this happen that a disk fails from one minute to another. " - same thing happened to my grandfather. One minute he was alive, the next minute he was dead.

Comment: No, the laptop wasn't dropped afaik. Thanks for your advise. I will just let this scan finish overnight and then give it to a professional.

Comment: It is very likely that the controller or a chip on the controller is dying. A data recovery specialist will troubleshoot this and if so, use a donor controller from an identical disk so that the data can be resurrected before considering the drive dead. The question is then, is the data important enough that you need to spend $5000+ for data recovery, or can you settle for just buying a new drive and start over, recovering from backups?

Comment: @beta the longer a drive with failing controller is on, the more damage you will do to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There definitely should be data on the hard drive. Windows is installed and he had a lot of documents and whatnot on the drive. How can it be, that it suddenly shows as completely empty and not bootable anymore?

Drives break. You experienced one way of it, but it is not the most common one I guess.

> Any hints on how I can repair the disk to a) keep the files and b) make it bootable again would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

> 2: ddrescue yields this. any opinions?

You won't repair it. Your ddrescue screen depicts a total desaster - nothing rescued, but a transfer speed of 8 MByte/sec across one unique erroneous area.
That is still a fast examination speed which lets me conclude that ddrescue's read attempts may never have reached the platters.

Contact a professional recovery company if your data is important to you.
German computer magazine c't has articles on recovery containing names of reputated companies.

**14.1.2020 0:05 UTC+1  added info relating to Update 3:**

Not every error condition does show up in SMART information.
It appears that you cut of the drive from power 70 times - as this has been logged your drive did not like it.

48° Celsius would be quite high for a rotating drive but still in spec. For a SSD I don't know. CrystalDiskInfo does not show the maximum temperature reached.
You better use smartmontools because you can redirect the output into an easy to post log file:
smartctl /dev/sdX > mylog.txt

Replace X by the drive letter in question. Read the wiki information about the -d switch when experiencing problems with external USB chipsets.

**14.1.2020 0:17 update relating to part quality**

Lite-On is not a flash manufacturer. They have to buy flash storage presumably on the spot market. If you buy the device again the flash storage inside could originate from another manufacturer or perhaps from the same one but at a different quality. I expect low quality flash storage not meeting quality manufacturer's spec to end up in low priced products. You either run backups or if you are lazy like me better stick with quality components.

Be aware that the above cannot be generalized to every Lite-On product. I have some very good Lite-On DVD-burners and readers that are unmatched by today's burners and readers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is NOT a hard drive. Its an SSD. Many SSDs (particularly no-name brand ones like this) fail suddenly and catastrophically - its likely a firmware related issue.

You are unlikely to be able to recover the data without engaging the services if a data recovery expert (who may be able to unsolder the chips and read the raw data)

Answer (score -3):

1st, it have reformat warning (on Windows)
2nd, it start slowly
3rd, overheat
4th, buzzing,weird sound (physical disc)
5th, final stage, random mount/unmount, and then die even when you power it up

the best thing you can do is clone (clone is much better) to another new drive

Comment: This does not help the OP as his symptoms are different to what you describe and that does not help him anyway - and he has already shown his efforts to clone the drive.